# How to correctly call an API in Google Cloud Functions with a Python Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to python and want to fetch data from an API via Google Cloud Functions so that I can store the data in Google Cloud Storage afterwards.

The data is available in JSON format and I want to transform it in a table via pandas.

Since I am really unsure about the correct syntax I'd like to know how I have to call the function test_topic - The following code doesn't work for me. I get no error message but also I get no result.

What do I have to do that I get the table as a result?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def test_topic(df):
    url = "https://api.domain.com/v1/"
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    parameters = {
        "api_key": "1234567890",
        "start_date": "2020-01",
        "end_date": "2021-01",
        "format": "json" 
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, params=parameters)

    df = response.json()['visits']  
    pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: You forgot to include the error messages.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I don't get no error message, it's just that i don't get no result.

Comment: What's the response status in your code?

Comment: repsonse status is 200

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that you probably need to authenticate your request against the Cloud Function. Unless the Cloud Function was deployed `--allow-unauthenticated` (permitting anyone), you're going to have to authenticate requests using an access (?) token (`TOKEN`):

```py
token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
headers=["Authorization"] = "Bearer: {token}".format(token=token)}
```

For development purposes, you can grab a token using `gcloud` and export this to your code:

```sh
export TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
python3 main.py
```

You should also:

```py
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
```

For debugging, you should consider:

```py
json_response = response.json()
print(json_response)
```

before you try to access `visits`, perhaps:

```py
if "visits" in json_response:
  # JSON response contains "visits"
else:
  # JSON response does not contain "visits"
```